# Could the US fed gov reduce a state's minimum wage?

Tags: united-states, constitution, federalism, minimum-wage

I haven't seen any discussion on this and so I am not clear on whether it can only add restrictions on top of existing state laws instead of removing restrictions.

Comment: Related: [In the US, what is the role of and relationship between federal law and state law?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26252/26455). While that question mentions minimum wage, it is not clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @RickSmith This is explicitly not a duplicate. I asked about whether the fed gov can remove restrictions in addition to adding restrictions, that only discusses adding the restriction of a higher minimum wage. Also you cannot simply preempt all questions about federalism sub-topics because there's one question about federalism writ large. That's like if one person asked "How does the government work" and then you redirected anyone asking a specific question about the government to that one forevermore

Comment: The other question was an attempt to answer a certain class of questions of which this question is one of that class. The second sentence was advisory, in that, one should use care in using that question as an attempt to close this question. It was not an attempt to preempt this question.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in the accepted answer of the other question: "In the particular mentioned example of federal vs. state (vs. local) minimum wages, the most restrictive (highest) minimum wage in a given jurisdiction would apply. So, if the federal government has a $7.25/hr minimum wage, but the state government has as $10 minimum wage, the minimum legal wage in that state is $10. If a city in that state then decides to impose a $12 minimum wage, then the minimum wage inside that city is $12."

Comment: Given the additional space a dedicated answer to this question provides, this should be separately sourced and expanded upon (which I am unfortunately not qualified for). A potential issue I would be interested in is: "Would a state minimum wage apply to federal employees working in that state?"

Comment: @xyldke *The answer to this question can be found in the accepted answer of the other question ...* No. This question asks: given a federal minimum of **X** and a state minimum of **Y**, where **Y** is greater than **X**, can the government set a limit **Z** such that **Z** is greater than **X** and less than **Y**; thus reducing the state's minimum wage. For example, $10 ≤ $14 < $15. An employer within the state paying $14/hr could use the federal wage law and the *supremacy clause* to defend against paying $15/hr, the state minimum.

Comment: @xyldke "the most restrictive (highest) minimum wage in a given jurisdiction would apply". I assume this means that the US can't reduce a state's minimum wage? But how is this different from e.g. how it can weaken *or* strengthen a state's abortion law using the commerce clause? Why can't it increase *or* reduce a state's minimum wage using the commerce clause? (Separately, on your second comment, what do you mean by the answer to this question should be "separately sourced"?)

Comment: I don't know how it's different. I only wanted to add the relevant part of the related question to provide additional context. With separate sourcing I mean that I would be interested in someone answering a question specifically about minimum wage with sources that tackle that specific issue. The other answer talks generally about the relationship, using minimum wage as an example. But this issue *settled* or *controversial*? "Why **can't** the federal government use the commerce clause? I think, these ancilliary questions deserve their own answer, which can be given under this question.

Comment: @xyldke Ok I was just saying that the answer that you quoted and gave appears to be incorrect, since it disagrees with another case study (that I trust was less reflexively answered).

Comment: It's not technically correct to say the most restrictive applies. Both apply. In practice, following the most restrictive also follows the less restrictive, so it's a useful rule of thumb but is not accurate.

Comment: @bharring It wouldn't be the most restrictive versus the less restrictive. Both of those are positively restrictive. It would be the most restrictive law versus a law overturning that restrictive law. I'm asking if the latter kind of law is possible in a federal to state relationship.

Comment: So: Can the Federal government pass laws regulating what regulations a State may impose?

Comment: @bharring Yes. Overturning or otherwise effectively removing state restrictions, instead of merely adding to them on top of them.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they can, but I know enough caveats to know it's not quite that simple, so hope a better answer comes along.

Comment: This question is better suited for law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user103496 Looking through the questions it looks like it's not likely to be big on theory or constitutional law. Most of it is people looking for personal advice

Comment: @user84614: You are mistaken. Law.SE covers all aspects of law and all countries. The answers there are also of much higher quality than here. Give it a try if you are serious about asking your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although it is a good question, it is a legal question, and thus better suited for law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @End Anti-Semitic Hate It fits squarely into the discussions about federalism and constitutional law here so unless you're going to move over those as well...

Answer (score 4):

Q: *Could the US fed gov reduce a state's minimum wage?*

Possibly. <sup>1</sup> Minimum wages are regulated under the [Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA)](https://www.dol.gov/agencies/whd/flsa).

> The Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA) establishes minimum wage, overtime pay, recordkeeping, and youth employment standards affecting employees in the private sector and in Federal, State, and local governments.

Something as innocuous as purchasing fast food in one state and driving to another state before eating is interstate commerce, but even that is not required.

If Congress decides that a cap on the minimum wage is necessary to achieve a "legitimate end", then the Court could <sup>2</sup> side with Congress. This despite the apparent meaning of "substantial" with respect to "effect on interstate commerce" (see below).

Such legitimate ends could include maintaining more entry-level jobs or preventing a rise in unemployment within the affected states; either or both of which would affect the national economy. (*See*, [What is the case against raising the minimum wage?](https://www.cnet.com/personal-finance/minimum-wage-by-state-2023/) for its general effects.)

**However**, such a law would not pass Congress because no Democrat would support it and most Republicans would be concerned about diminishing their chances for re-election. <sup>3</sup>

---

[Limits on Federal Regulation of Intrastate Activity](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C3-6-5/ALDE_00013422/)

> ... the three broad categories of activity that Congress may regulate or protect under its commerce power: (1) the use of the channels of interstate commerce; (2) the use of instrumentalities of interstate commerce; or (3) activities that substantially affect interstate commerce.

Neither 1 nor 2 apply. The question then is whether wages paid at any state's high minimum wage *substantially affect interstate commerce*.

[Intrastate Activities Having a Substantial Relation to Interstate Commerce](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S8-C3-6-4/ALDE_00013421/)

> In *United States v. Lopez*, the Court identified activities having a substantial relation to interstate commerce as being subject to Congress’s Commerce Clause power. Consequently, Congress’s power extends beyond transactions or actions that involve crossing state or national boundaries to activities that, though local in nature, sufficiently affect commerce. The Court has stated that, even activity that is purely intrastate in character may be regulated by Congress, where the activity, combined with like conduct by others similarly situated, affects commerce among the States or with foreign nations. This power derives from the Commerce Clause supplemented by the Necessary and Proper Clause.

> ... the Court stated, the commerce power ‘extends to those activities intrastate which so affect interstate commerce, or the exertion of the power of Congress over it, as to make regulation of them appropriate means to the attainment of a legitimate end, the effective execution of the granted power to regulate interstate commerce.’ Judicial review is narrow. A court must defer to Congress’s determination of an effect if it is rational, and Congress must have acted reasonably in choosing the means.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am only willing to stick out my neck just so far. There is no suitable precedent I could find.
<sup>2</sup> Still preserving my neck.
<sup>3</sup> My neck is safe.

Comment: Thanks. How would Congress phrase that? Minimum wage laws are illegal? Or no state government may prevent an individual from being employed at a certain rate? I'm only familiar with laws regulating private individuals and businesses so I'm not sure how they would regulate state governments, wording-wise.

Comment: @user84614 - They would probably, suitably modify [29 U.S. Code § 206 - Minimum wage](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/29/206) to create an exception under paragraph (a) to identify state minimum wages and add text expressing the limits. I have no idea how it would be expressed.

Comment: Something just feels very unintuitive about a law regulating what laws can exist, even if they're state laws. Outside of the Constitution (which I know has been applied to state laws). So I just want to confirm. Hopefully I'll find an answer someplace

Comment: @user84614 It is not "a law regulating what laws can exist", but stating which are the limits to state laws. The Interstate Commerce Clause was used, among other things, to forbid racial discrimination in accomodation. If there is a federal law, and SCOTUS holds that its reach is within the powers of the federal powers, then all state (and lower laws) contradicting it are invalid.

Comment: Or put the other way: if a state issued a law setting a minimum wage that is under the federal limit, that law would be invalid. So the very example you point in your question is a law that limits the states ability to issue laws. A law setting a maximum would not be that different, provided that SCOTUS agreed that it was constitutional.

Comment: @user84614 In most cases there's a rational relationship between the powers enumerated for Congress in the Constitution and how it gives them the power to pass a law, and if Congress has the power to regulate something then states can't contradict federal regulation.  The Commerce Clause is special because SCOTUS has ruled that Congress has the power to pass anything they want as long as it includes a reference to interstate commerce, so I think the argument in the answer is that it could be used to preempt state laws.  Maybe the answer could briefly explain federal preemption.

Comment: @SJuan76 A State law setting a minimum wage below the federal minimum wage would be valid. It mostly wouldn't matter because people would usually comply with the federal law. But in the details, both laws are on effect.

Comment: For an example of how dual sovergnty works, look at pot. Most states make it illegal. Federal law makes it illegal. A State removing their law making it illegal doesn't actually make pot legal. But the difference in enforcement means its effectively legal.